# Angular view doesn't get update on variable changes

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, angular5

I'm working with Angular 5.  In a `@Output()` `EventEmitter`, when I get some variable emitted, in the binding function, although I can have the value changed and console, it didn't reflect in the view side.

The following is the code of what I described above:

```html
{{ visible }} <!-- visible remains "true" before and after emit -->

<app-my-component (objChange)="onChange($event)"></app-my-component>
```

```js
onChange(obj) {
  this.var = obj.var;
  this.visible = false;
  console.log(this.visible); // which logs "false" correctly.
}
```

I triggered my emitter in Google Maps marker event listener:

```js
marker.addListener('click', () => {
    this.objChange.emit(obj);
});
```

I've been working with Angular 4+ for quite a while (almost a year), and this never happened before.  What may be different (but I don't know if any of them may be the reason) this time are:

1. the `EventEmitter` is somehow triggered by Google Maps API (imported with `@types/googlemaps`)
2. I updated my `@angular/cli` to version 6 last week (while the project remains version 5)

Which seems weirder to me, this problem only happens when I starts my project on this page.  (That is, if I head to another page then come back, it works.)  Restart `ng serve` or try to use `rxjs` both failed for me.  If anyone had ever encountered the same problem, could you share how you fix that?  Thank you!

Comment: Can you show how you emit the objChange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you're using Google Maps and some sort of async function, and in the callback you run `this.objChange.emit()`.

This will cause Angular not to be aware of what you just did and as a result it will not trigger change detection.

The easy fix is to import `NgZone` and wrap the emit of the `@Output` in its `run` function:

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

someAsyncGoogleFunction
  .then(() => {

    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.objChange.emit();
    });
  })
```

Comment: yes it works, thank you for helping with the problem & telling me another method (using NgZone in some async situation) working with ng!

Comment: Glad I could help :)